# Difference between two months - only based on months and not date

Tags: c#, date

I am currently using below code to find month difference between two dates.

```
var WatMonths = ((WatInjEndDate.Year - WaterStartDate.Year) * 12) + WatInjEndDate.Month - WaterStartDate.Month
```

For example:

```
WaterStartDate = 9/28/2015
WaterInjEndDate = 12/4/2015
```

The answer that I get from above code is 3. But my ultimate requirement is to get "4" that depicts months 9,10,11,12 as WaterStartDate is in the 9th month and Enddate is in 12th month of the year.

What should I modify in the code?

Comment: Add 1 to WatMonths (not a joke!)

Comment: It's a general math rule, to get the count of something: (endIndex- startIndex) + 1.

Comment: and what result you are expecting for 9/1/2015 and 9/28/2015 ? if the result is 1 - the answer is posted in comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you are defining the *number of months between dates* as being inclusive of both the month of start date and the end date. So the number of months between 2015/1/1 and 2015/1/1 would be 1. Are you sure this is the behavior you want?

In order to accomplish the behavior you described, simply add `+ 1` to the end of your assignment.

```
var WatMonths = ((WatInjEndDate.Year - WaterStartDate.Year) * 12) + 
                    WatInjEndDate.Month - WaterStartDate.Month + 1
```

Comment: Thanks! It's easier than I made it !

Comment: @Cartman23: Just be careful when calculating injection water duration... ;-) From my industry experience you may want to represent partial months instead (typical for "Days Online"/"Months Online" calculations).

Comment: I agree. but this will be used for calculation and inventory in future. Hence, will be based on Days online = Days of the month.

Comment: @Cartman23: As long as you are getting the rate/volume calculations correct you should be fine! Also, if my answer solved your question, it would be good to mark it as the accepted answer.